# Why does converting ushort port number from htons to ntohs in C# give different result?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

I'm sending a port number (ushort, 2 bytes) over socket, (c++ client) before that converting it to network bytes using htons.

When receiving, using C# server, I'm converting it using `IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder` and the number is completely different.

```
htons(8085) -> 38175 ??
IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(38175) -> ??
```

What's the cause of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike the BSD sockets API, where there's a separate name for each function, in .NET the `NetworkToHostOrder` method is overloaded, and may perform either `ntohs` or `ntohl` depending on the size of the input.

You're passing in a 32-bit integer input (`int` is the default type when C# sees a literal unless it doesn't fit), and therefore you get the same result as `ntohl` not `ntohs`.

If you want `ntohs` behavior, change the input type, e.g.

```
IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((short)38175)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's making sense now. :)